# how to install a python patch from twisted on windows?

Tags: python, python-2.7, twisted, twisted.web, twisted.client

I want to install a python patch for twisted that allows me to enter data via console (stdio). Please help me how to use this patch

Here's the link - https://twistedmatrix.com/trac/ticket/2157

Comment: I'm sorry that Twisted doesn't implement the functionality you need.  However, if you're not already fluent in the techniques required to download source code and apply patches, you are probably not ready to accept the responsibility of running a hacked version of Twisted.  Given that it's hard enough to actually support the versions of Twisted that we actually test and release, we'd really prefer it if you didn't start putting patched versions into the wild.

Comment: However, if you'd like to help get that ticket merged into Twisted proper and accepted so that it's in a release you can use, we'd be very to help you do that!